# Bash Script: replace white space with "\ " in string

Tags: string, bash, shell, replace, sh

I am currently iterating for a value similar to this:

```
Administer PoolA servers :id=server@Pool@5@example.com
```

and would like to replace the white spaces with "\ " in order to have it look like this (or add \ before every whitespace):

```
Administer\ PoolA\ servers\ :id=server@Pool@5@example.com
```

I am aware regex would help me do this, but have been unsuccessful, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the context here? Usually, adding literal backslashes is the Wrong Thing (that is, doesn't accomplish what you intend to do), *particularly* if you expect that generating a string in this manner will let you expand the variable that contains it unquoted and have the result parse as a single word; whereas, using your variable which contains such a value in a correctly-quoted context may moot the issue. Make sure [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) doesn't apply.

Comment: Also, you have both `bash` and `sh` tagged. These are two different shells, and would call for two different answers: The best-practice bash answer (assuming you *really do* want to add literal backslashes to your string) would use a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) which `/bin/sh` doesn't support; please tag only one or the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to use a regular expression for this. You can use the bash [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)  operator for string replacement.

```
$ str='Administer PoolA servers :id=server@Pool@5@example.com'
$ newStr="${str// /\\ }"
$ echo "$newStr"
Administer\ PoolA\ servers\ :id=server@Pool@5@example.com
```

Comment: Personally, I'd make it `${str// /'\ '}` just to be *completely* clear that the backslash is literal rather than relying on fallback behavior for unrecognized backslash-escape sequences -- but obviously, this works either way.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I originally had an escaped backslash, then saw that I didn't need to escape it, so I posted that version, not realizing it was a fallback behavior.

Comment: I can never remember whether it's single or double quotes that recognize escape sequences. :(

Comment: This solution works perfectly for my use case, thanks

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'd stick with the escaped version, because the single-quoted version will treat the single-quotes as literal *if* the whole thing is in double-quotes. That is, `newStr=${str// /'\ '}` works, but `newStr="${str// /'\ '}"` and `echo "${str// /'\ '}"` both put literal single-quotes in the final string. Wheee!

Comment: @GordonDavisson, *nod* -- I actually prefer `src=' '; repl='\ '; newStr=${str//$src/$repl}` for my own code, but it's a mouthful to put in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring="Administer PoolA servers :id=server@Pool@5@example.com"
echo "$mystring" | sed "s/ /\\\ /g"
# --> Administer\ PoolA\ servers\ :id=server@Pool@5@example.com
```

Comment: This is buggy -- if the string contains a `*`, the result of your command will have a list of filenames in it.

Comment: And if it contains multiple spaces in a row, they'll be combined into a single space. You should generally quote your variables.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. If I quote the variable, will it remedy both issues?

Comment: Yes. It'll still be slower than necessary, but quoting the variable will remedy both issues mentioned above. (There are still some corner cases caused by `echo`; if `mystring="-n"`, for instance, output is undefined; `printf '%s\n' "$mystring"` is a bit more reliable than `echo "$mystring"`, though adding the quotes fixes the biggest issues). See also [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo), and the APPLICATION USAGE section of the [POSIX `echo` spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html).